# Vertices of THREE.BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Since r125, `THREE.Geometry` was deprecated. We are now updating our code base and we are running into errors that we don't know how to fix.

We create a sphere and use a raycaster on the sphere to get the intesect point.

```html
worldSphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
        worldSize,
        worldXSegments,
        worldYSegments
);

...

const intersect = raycaster.intersectObjects([worldGlobe])[0];

...

if (intersect) {
    let a = worldSphere.vertices[intersect.face.a];
    let b = worldSphere.vertices[intersect.face.b];
    let c = worldSphere.vertices[intersect.face.c];
}
```

Now, normally variable `a` would contain 3 values for every axis namely `a.x, a.y, a.z`, same goes for the other variables. However, this code does not work anymore.
We already know that `worldSphere` is of type `THREE.BufferGeometry` and that the vertices are stored in a `position` attribute, but we cannot seem to get it working.

What is the best way to fix our issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```js
const positionAttribute = worldGlobe.geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );
const a = new THREE.Vector3();
const b = new THREE.Vector3();
const c = new THREE.Vector3();

// in your raycasting routine

a.fromBufferAttribute( positionAttribute, intersect.face.a );
b.fromBufferAttribute( positionAttribute, intersect.face.b );
c.fromBufferAttribute( positionAttribute, intersect.face.c );
```

BTW: If you only raycast against a single object, use `intersectObject()` and not `intersectObjects()`.